# convert full date string to date mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database which contains string like this

> 22 Jan 2019 11:03

I would like to convert this string to date so I apply this query

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d-%m-%Y') ,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

but I get a null result

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/
You can also try out your examples here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-str_to_date/#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change small letter `m` to big letter `M` in your `str_to_date` function.

```
select STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d %M %Y');
```

so the final query would be:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d %M %Y') ,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f96311f0638da58ac29c47dfee22305)

Comment: Hi @M.Bwe hehehe that was fast, up and back down again. Well important thing is you know how to do it :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d,%m,%Y');

Answer (score 0):

Basically you first need to understand the values to pass in `STR_TO_DATE()` and `DATE_FORMAT()` functions

```
STR_TO_DATE(my date string , current format of my date string)
```

Now what you are not doing right is that in `STR_TO_DATE()` you are passing the format `'%d-%m-%Y'` , this format says that the input string has hyphen separated date month and year values which is not true.

Now in your case the actual format of your date string is the following

```
'%d %M %Y %h:%i'

 STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d %M %Y %h:%i')
```

- %d  - day
- %M  - month
- %Y  - year
- %h  - hour
- %i - minute

For more info on formats [click](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Now that we have a complete valid value from string to date including hour and minutes, we can convert this date into any of our required format using correct [parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('22 Jan 2019 11:03','%d %M %Y %h:%i') ,'%d-%m-%y %h:%i');
```

You can try out various examples here

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-str_to_date/#1